# Tabs add extra space in IE based on screen resolution or window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on tab design as show below [image]

Image one
Image 2 [image]

If you look closely you will notice that it add white space after last TAB... After further trouble shouting i noticed that this spacing show up only when  you change the window size in my case it show up ONLY in IE 9 when i change the it to IE 8 Standard view it just goes away.

These tabs come up perfectly on Chrome & Firefox. I only have problem with IE it might show up or not show up depending on the window size & screen resolution.

I am not able to figure out the source of the problem or solution.

I am adding screen shot just to show you guys as i am not sure if this will show up on your screen or not.

as it is just 1 pixel different only. But need to be fixed for IE.  i tried setting margin padding for UL LI and other elements but nothing works.

I request you to re size IE window slow to see the different as it will fit or un fit automatically.

Any help in this regard is appreciate. So far this has driven me crazy i am not sure of this is BUG in IE or what.

NOTE: This problem is with IE browser only
jsFiddle link also http://jsfiddle.net/xd465/1/

I have set jsbin sample also http://jsbin.com/UJIgUla/1

SOURCE CODE:

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div class="tabs-wrapper margin00-10-0">
    <div class="tab-name-wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a class="tabs-item-a-4 active" href="#tab4"><div class="d-tab-title-w-1">NEWS</div></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="tabs-item-a-1" href="#tab1"><div class="d-tab-title-w-2">THE TAB 2</div></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="tabs-item-a-2" href="#tab2"><div class="d-tab-title-w-3">THE TAB 3</div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content-wrapper">
        <div id="tab1" style="display: none;">
            <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlTheChairman">
                <p>Try the new improved Lorem Ipsum Generator Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui sed dolor, integer sagittis. Non volutpat eveniet, adipiscing erat, nunc sed quis. Maecenas diam, pellentesque consectetuer, dui felis ut. Vestibulum pharetra faucibus./p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" style="display: none;">
            <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlChairmanMSG">
                <p>Try the new improved Lorem Ipsum Generator Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui sed dolor, integer sagittis. Non volutpat eveniet, adipiscing erat, nunc sed quis. Maecenas diam, pellentesque consectetuer, dui felis ut. Vestibulum pharetra faucibus./p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4">
            <div class="hp-news-list"> <a href="#">
                                <div class="hp-news-td-w">
                                    <div class="hp-news-title"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rptNews_lblNewsTitle_0">   Try the new improved Lorem Ipsum Generator
</span></div>
                                    <div class="hp-news-date"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rptNews_lblDate_0">05-AUG-2013</span></div>

                                </div>
                             </a>

                <hr class="hp-news-hr">
            </div>
            <div class="hp-news-list"> <a href="#">
                                <div class="hp-news-td-w">
                                    <div class="hp-news-title"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rptNews_lblNewsTitle_1">Try the new improved Lorem Ipsum Generator</span></div>
                                    <div class="hp-news-date"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rptNews_lblDate_1">02-AUG-2013</span></div>

                                </div>
                             </a>

                <hr class="hp-news-hr">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Tabs End-->
```

Comment: Can you upload your code in jsfiddle so that it will be easy to edit and provide you with the result.

Comment: jsFiddle Sample link http://jsfiddle.net/xd465/1/

Comment: I can see the difference, so, yeah. But there is a humongous amount of CSS in there; can't you prune that so that there is just enough left to show the issue? And it might even point you to the solution yourself!